# Explanation for output of given code

Tags: c, function, output, function-pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int a, int b, int c) {
    return a + b + c / 2;
}

void main() {
    int (*function_pointer)(int, int, int);     // how this will be interpreted
    function_pointer = sum;
    printf("%d", function_pointer(2, 3, 4));
    return ;
}
```

When i ran on ide it gave output 7, i dont understand how?

Comment: first line is #include <stdio.h> sorry for that

Comment: fixed that for you

Comment: What output were you *expecting*? And why the deuce to you call a function "sum" that has a division in it?

Comment: `2 + 3 + 4 / 2 = 7` which is ok. If you meant average of all together, use parentheses: `(2 + 3 + 4) / 2 = 4`

Comment: @tilz0R: But beware the spectre of integer arithmetic. That'll be the next thing.

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
int (*function_pointer)(int, int, int);
```

declares a pointer to a function that accepts three `int` arguments and return an `int`. Latter this is pointed to function `sum`  and used to call the function.

Inside the `sum` function the statement

```
return a + b + c / 2;
```

is parsed as

```
return a + b + (c / 2); // division operator has higher precedence than + operator 
                       //  and therefore the operands `c` and `2` will be bind to `/` operator
```

Comment: Nice answer but I think the OP is struggling with infant-level operator precedence knowledge.

Comment: @Bathsheba according to comment in OPs code, answer is directly for his struggling.

Comment: @Bathsheba; "Infant" was hilarious :D

Answer (score 0):

this:

```
int (*function_pointer)(int, int, int);
```

means you are defining a function pointer with the name **function_pointer** that can be used as alias for ANY other function that ***takes 3 integers as parameter*** an ***returns an integer***

then when you do this:

```
function_pointer = sum;
```

you are assigning the address of the function sum to the function_pointer, that means later, you can do both:

```
function_pointer(2, 3, 4)
```

or

```
sum(2, 3, 4)
```

---

now to the result, and why is printing out **7**

```
a + b + c / 2
```

with 2,3,4 is the same as **2 + 3 + 4 / 2**  or **2 + 3 + 2 = 7**

Comment: I understood , only one question will function_pointer() point to all functions (whose return type is int and takes three int arguments) or to only those which are assigned to it.

Comment: Hi @amankhunt, is like a pointer, but only that it holds the address of another function... and yes... it will work only with  those which are assigned to it : )